# For loop in Java using comma

Tags: java

Below is the code written in java

```
for (int a = 1,int b = 4; a < b; a++, b--)
                System.out.println("a = " + a + " b=" + b);
```

It shows syntax error in int . Please tell me the reason for syntax inside for loop.
when we declare int a,b , it does not show error.

Comment: remove `int` before `b`

Comment: @Anand, this is a syntactical issue, which is available on tons of sites and you should check it out to fix such issues before posting question.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

remove "int" before b

```
import java.util.*;
    public class fib{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            for (int a = 1, b = 4; a < b; a++, b--) // reomve int before b
                    System.out.println("a = " + a + " b=" + b);
        }
    }
```